# Jmeter - Internal server error 500 in jmeter response code

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have recorded script in jmeter V3.3 via IE browser and then done correlation. When I run this script, then it is receiving internal server error 500 in response, however it works fine manually in IE browser and also while recording this scenario, it does not occur.

I also cross verified Header manager with Request Headers in network IE F12 Developer tool and it is uptodate.

[Sampler Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VX721.jpg)

[Http Get Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2zjn.jpg)

It is simply Get request. I really appreciate for your help to handle this error in jmeter.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have compared both Request Headers one from IE Browser and from JMETER request headers to check if anything is not missing to pass. And also along with any dynamic id is not missing.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely not checking for expected results with each step.  As a result, you are receiving an HTTP 200 correct response page prior to your HTTP 500, but the content of the page is out of context with the expected results for the business process.  When you make your next request the state of the application is not appropriate to your request.  As an unhandled condition by the developer you are greeted with an HTTP 500 screen dump.

Most likely cause: Unhandled dynamic data component.